# Button not receiving touch while table view is scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, button

In my cell, there's a button which works normally (changing the background color) when the scrollview isn't scrolling. But when it's scrolling, pressing the button still changes the background color but doesn't return to it's original color after the touch has ended. I suspect that `touchesEnded(withEvent:)` won't get called when the scrollview is scrolling.

That being said, I've been trying to implement the methods

```
touchesShouldCancelInContentView(_:)
touchesShouldBegin(withEvent:, inContentView:)
```

in a subclass of `UITableView` so the touches won't get canceled, but it doesn't seem to be fixing the problem.

The view controller:

```
class PaymentViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func pressed(sender: UIButton) {
        print("pressed") // This won't get called when scrollview is scrolling
    }
}
```

---

**My question is:**
To be able to make my button behave with all the touches, can the methods mentioned before fix this problem? If yes, how should I implement them?

Comment: try setting contentview UserInteraction to off and bringSubviewToFront the button

Comment: The button is working fine, I reacts to the touches even while scrolling. It's just that it seems the touches are getting canceled when the scrollview is scrolling.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to click button while scrollview is scrolling.